# C#: Parse Nested XML File With Same Tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<grid table="Declaration">
    <primary_key>Some String</primary_key>
    <query>
        Some String
    </query>
    <grid table="GoodsItem">
        <foreign_key>Some String</foreign_key>
        <primary_key>Some String</primary_key>
        <query>
            Some String
        </query>
        <grid table="GoodsItemGUID">
            <foreign_key>Some String</foreign_key>
            <foreign_key>Some String</foreign_key>
            <primary_key>Some String</primary_key>
            <query>
                Some String
            </query>
        </grid>
    </grid>
</grid>
```

As you can see "grid" element contains same "grid" elements, that can also contain "grid" elements, so i want to parse this xml file in general way not only for this xml file. what is best way to do it?

I tried this code, but it just takes grid elements, for example it doesn't know that "GoodsItem" is child of "Declaration". thats the main problem i want to solve.

```
MyClass curr = new MyClass ();

XmlNodeList gridNodes = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("grid");
            foreach (XmlNode bookNode in gridNodes)
            {
                MyClass child = new MyClass ();
                curr.Child = child;
                curr = child;
                curr.Table = bookNode.Attributes["table"].Value;
                curr.PrimaryKey = bookNode["primary_key"].InnerText;
                curr.Query = bookNode["query"].InnerText;
            }
```

Comment: By using an XML parser?

Comment: Can you give sample code? i tried, but I couldn't find out which "grid" elements had which parents.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want to do. Show us your code that you tried.

Comment: on this particular example, this code works, but it is not general, for example if there was 2 "grid" nodes in "grid" node, for my code it wouldn't make difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the parent node with [`bookNode.ParentNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.parentnode(v=vs.110).aspx).
And you can check if the parent node is `<grid>`, by checking, if the property [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.name(v=vs.110).aspx) of the parent is `grid`.

```
if (bookNode.ParentNode != null && bookNode.ParentNode.Name == "grid")
{
     XmlNode parent_grid = bookNode.ParentNode;
     // do something with parent_grid
}
```

Comment: @Nikoloz14 You should accept the answer, if it answered your question.